# Bulk Join to Azure AD - Best Practices

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-networking

I am wondering what is the best practice when joining corporate owned machines to Azure. We have no on-prem AD/DC, solely Azure AD. I have an upcoming project with a new office opening with 40 machines, and 35 users a combination of all corporate owned laptops and desktops.

I am coming from a traditional background where when a new devices are brought in, it is imaged, joined to the domain, then given to the user. I want to achieve the same process with Azure - I need them to be managed by Intune, be able to deploy Computer Policies, not just Mobile policies; and I need the devices to be properly linked to the user who uses it.

SO... Is it better to:

a. Open "Users may join devices to AzureAD" to ALL users and limit the number of devices - Image the machine, then have the END USER go through the steps to Join to AzureAD via settings under their own account

b. Set "Users may join devices to Azure AD" to some Admin group with our Tech's user accounts, set device limit to Unlimited - Image the machine, join the machine to Azure under my own/the tech's own company account, then deploy to end user

c. Create a limited admin for the sole purpose of enrolling machines to AzureAD, limit "Users may join devices to AzureAD" to a custom group for the enrollment user, set device limit to Unlimited -- Image the machine and use this one and only account to join the device to Azure.

In any of these methods, how will it effect users BYOD? Most users will bring their smartphone or tablet/hybrid in, and I want those registered, but not joined. I still want to deploy basic compliance policies, but they are not corporate devices, and no tech will lay hands on those devices for set up so it needs to be simple for the user.

Comment: Be careful.. AzureAD isn't the same as real active directory. https://jumpcloud.com/blog/replace-on-premise-ad-azure-ad/

Comment: Out of the box AAD doesn't support domain join except with Windows 10 machines. You can enable Azure AD Directory Services to be able to join other devices, however as Tim mentioned there are limitations, which are you planning to use? Azure AD isn't really designed as an on prem AD replacment

Comment: I am aware that it is not a replacement for traditional AD, but we are not large enough to justify the expenses for a on-prem data center. Plus we deal with patient health information and rely on Microsoft's Cloud to handle security.

Everything is cloud based, no network drives, and InTune's policies are more than enough for what we need.

All devices are Windows 10 Pro+, iPhone, Android or Windows phone. No Windows 7, 8, or 8.1

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer the question, are you deploying Azure AD Domain services, or are you using the Win 10 AAD join, as they are different services.

Comment: I was planning on AAD join, I am not too familiar with AAD DS.

I guess I am a little confused about the options available for us to use.

Comment: Just an update: According to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEvwbw3hW6M

Domain join via AD DS is NOT recommended, and it is recommended to use Azure AD Join instead.
Still unsure of the best practice, because I do not want to put the user through an OOB experience. I want a turnkey solution for our clients.

Comment: What is your requirement, do you want to give control to the user to automatically join to azure ad when deploying using intune pre provision for example, or do you want to have maximum control and deliver fully deployed and joined devices to your users?